# Object moved | downloading with url

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to download zip file with curl from subscene.com

Like this site: http://tinysub.us/subtitles/mad-max-fury-road/english/1139220

when click "Download English Subtitle" site is work and beginning downloading zip file .

but it gives Object moved to here error

```
<?php


if(isset($_GET['link'])) {
$endlink = $_GET['link'];
echo get("http://subscene.com/" . $endlink);

} 
else
echo get("http://subscene.com/");


function get($link) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10 ); // timeout
return $html =  curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
}
?>
```